# How to check recovered depth

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am using disparity map generation from 2 stereoscopic images .And then I use the normal triangulation formula depth= focallength*baseline/disparity to get the depth .How can I check that the recovered depth is indeed correct? Is there some test for  this ? I guess there are some tweak-able parameters like multiplying this depth by some factor etc but again that is more of trial and error.I am looking for something more concrete.How do people in the vision community generally verify the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you verify the depth measured in your images by measuring it in the real world. If there was a way to verify the measurement you did in the images .. *in* the images then you probably would have used that way to measure depth in the first place.

Measure the distance from your camera to some object in the real world, and measure the size of the object perpendicular to the axis of one of the camera's. Then also measure the distance and size in your images. You use the size measure in the real world combined with the size of the object in pixels in the image to scale the distance you calculate. The result should match the distance you mesaured.